# Azure function triggered from dynamic list of queues

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

We’re trying to create a functionality where we can create individual user queues so that the downstream apps can process each user messages at a different pace in-order.

And when any of those queues have messages, we’d like to trigger the same Azure function for all the queues.

Not supported by ServiceBusTrigger on Azure function, since it requires a function per queue to be configured at deployment time.

All suggestions welcome!

PS: We’re okay to deploy new pieces of wiring when new queues are created.

Comment: How many users are expected to be using this solution? What at the downstream apps a d what do they do? What does your entire solution trying to achieve from a business processes perspective?

Comment: good point by Sean. Why do you want to do that? can't you just use a single Queue/Topic ?

Comment: This solution is like an Enterprise event bus, it allows each user application register their own webhook subscriber queue through a self service portal. And the function that is triggered calls the webhook callback endpoint. 


We need this solution to accommodate applications accepting and processing the data at their own pace (and may individually go down during their deployments/failures). The number of subscribers could be roughly 50-100